# SAS Recursive Join

Tags: sas

I have a large table of connections, and would like to expand that table to include recursive connections.

My data looks like this --

```
data city_list;  

input from_city $ to_city $;
datalines;  
PORTLAND SEATTLE
SEATTLE BOISE
BOISE PORTLAND
PORTLAND HELENA
NYC ORLANDO
ORLANDO MIAMI
;
run;
```

I'd like expand the data set to include stopovers, so it ends up looking like this.  I'm not concerned about whether I have both a "PORTLAND/SEATTLE" and a "SEATTLE/PORTLAND" record -- I can handle those afterwards as necessary.

```
BOISE   HELENA
BOISE   PORTLAND
BOISE   SEATTLE
NYC MIAMI
NYC ORLANDO
ORLANDO MIAMI
PORTLAND    HELENA
PORTLAND    SEATTLE
SEATTLE HELENA
```

I've tried using the following macro, but ran into performance problems when there were too many levels of recursion.  I believe the best option would be hash tables, but am not sure how to code this precise scenario.

```
data city_list;  

input from_city $ to_city $;
datalines;  
PORTLAND SEATTLE
SEATTLE BOISE
BOISE PORTLAND
PORTLAND HELENA
NYC ORLANDO
ORLANDO MIAMI
;
run;

%macro RecurJoin(
baseTbl,
destTbl,
baseKey,
compKey
);

Proc SQL;
Create Table WORK.RECUR_JOIN_TBL as
SELECT distinct Base.&baseKey, Connect.&compkey
  FROM &baseTbl AS Base
       INNER JOIN &baseTbl AS Connect
          ON (Base.&compkey = Connect.&baseKey)
       LEFT JOIN &baseTbl AS Subbase
          ON (Base.&baseKey = Subbase.&baseKey) AND
             (Connect.&compkey = Subbase.&compkey)
 WHERE Subbase.&baseKey IS NULL;
quit;

  proc sql noprint;
    select count(1) into :connectCnt from RECUR_JOIN_TBL;
  quit;

Data &destTbl;
  set &baseTbl
      RECUR_JOIN_TBL;
run;

    Proc DataSets nolist;
        Delete RECUR_JOIN_TBL;
    Quit;

%if &connectCnt > 0 %then %do;
    %RecurJoin(
    baseTbl=&destTbl,
    destTbl=&destTbl,
    baseKey=&baseKey,
    compKey=&compKey
    );
%end;

%mend;

%RecurJoin(
baseTbl=city_list,
destTbl=FNL_CITY_LIST,
baseKey=from_city,
compKey=to_city
);

Proc Sort data=WORK.FNL_CITY_LIST (where=(NOT(from_city=to_city)));
  by from_city to_city;
run;
```

Comment: The best data structure to solve this kind of problem (provided there's no infinite-recursion) is a flattened tree structure.  Depending on how often you're going to query the data set, and your performance requirements this may be overkill.  Here's some good examples to get started.  If I have time tomorrow I'll have a crack at a proper answer, but maybe you'll beat me too it =) Example 1) http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/  and Example 2) http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html

Comment: Thank you for the links!  Do you have any information on this for a SAS context?

Comment: I'm putting something together but it may be a few more days as I'm pretty busy right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory allowing, you can use the hash-based approach I came up with in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342750/sas-grouping-pairs/32412518#32412518) to identify the groups of connected cities within your dataset. Then you just need to generate a row for every pair of cities within the same group, which can easily be done via a cartesian join in `proc sql`.

Comment: I tried this code with the following dataset, and it didn't work as expected -- it grouped all of these ids into a single set, rather than two sets.  Do you have any ideas how I could fix this?
I tried this code with the following dataset, and it didn't work as expected -- it grouped all of these ids into a single set, rather than two sets.

data have;
input id1 id2;
cards;
345488 356536
345488 357799
351491 351598
351491 351600
351598 351600
356536 357799;
run;

Comment: @Netbrian I think I've spotted the cause of the problem and I've updated the code in that answer, but I can't test it just now. Please have another look when you have a chance and see if it works as expected.

Comment: This seems to have worked!  I'm going to experiment with it a bit more later today before closing the question, but things are looking positive.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I've now tested it as well and I would tend to agree. Let me know if you find any other erroneous behaviour.