# SAS or SQL: re-arrange a table based on relation between variable values

Tags: sql, sorting, sas

In SAS, I have a table which contains two columns (variables) called parent and child. I want to transform this table to two different arrangements.

One example of this table is:

```
Obs number | parent | child
----------------------------
1          | D      | B
2          | J      | Q
3          | D      | S
4          | K      | J
5          | T      | U
6          | B      | T
```

The rules to build this table are that:

1. In each row (observation), the value in parent column is the parent of the value in the child column.
   For example, in row 1 and 2, we find D is B's parent and B is D's child; J is Q' parent and Q is J's child.

   ```
   Obs number | parent | child
   ----------------------------
   1          | D      | B
   2          | J      | Q
   ```
2. One parent can have several child. For example, in row 1 and 3, we find both B and S are D's child.

   ```
   Obs number | parent | child
   ----------------------------
   1          | D      | B
   ...        
   3          | D      | S
   ```
3. One child can have only one parent. For example, B's parent is D and B should not be child of any parent other than D. The following form is not allowed:

   ```
   Obs number | parent | child
   ----------------------------
   1          | D      | B
   ...
   n          | C      | B
   ```
4. A child can have its own child and a parent can have its own parent. For example, in row 1 and 6, we find B is D's child and it has its own child T:

   ```
   Obs number | parent | child
   ----------------------------
   1          | D      | B
   ...
   6          | B      | T
   ```

   in row 2 and 4, we find J is Q's parent and it has its own parent K:

   ```
   Obs number | parent | child
   ----------------------------
   2          | J      | Q
   ...
   4          | K      | J
   ```
5. A child should not be its own parent's parent and a parent should not be its own child's child. For example, B is a child from D, it can not be D's parent again. The following form is not allowed:

   ```
   Obs number | parent | child
   ----------------------------
   1          | D      | B
   ...
   n          | B      | D
   ```

The above ones are all the required rules to build the original table. Then I want to transform the table into two different arrangements.

First, I want to sort this table such that the related rows of parent and child are get together and form a link from the oldest parent to the youngest child. By this, I mean a transformation from the original table at left to the transformed table at right as shown below:

```
Original table:                          Transformed table:

Obs number | parent | child              Obs number | parent | child
----------------------------             ----------------------------
1          | D      | B                  1          | D      | S
2          | J      | Q                  2          | D      | B 
3          | D      | S         TO:      3          | B      | T 
4          | K      | J                  4          | T      | U
5          | T      | U                  5          | K      | J
6          | B      | T                  6          | J      | Q
```

Second, I want to transform the original table to a new table such that each row of the new table contains columns from the oldest parent to the youngest child. By this I mean a transformation like below:

```
Original table:                          Transformed table:

Obs number | parent | child              Obs number | var1 | var2 | var3 | var4
----------------------------             --------------------------------------
1          | D      | B                  1          | D    | B    | T    | U
2          | J      | Q                  2          | K    | J    | Q    | .
3          | D      | S         TO:      3          | D    | S    | .    | .
4          | K      | J 
5          | T      | U
6          | B      | T
```

Here are the SAS code to set-up the original table for test:

```
data original_table;
    input parent $ child $;
    datalines;
D      B
J      Q
D      S
K      J
T      U
B      T
;
```

Someone asked me for minimal attempts that I have tried. So here it is. I actually find a way to do the second transformation several hours after I posted here. Here are the code:

```
%macro TransformTable(lib=, dt=, output=);
/* rename the variable in the input table */
proc sql noprint;
    select cats(name,"=",cats(upcase("var"),substr("12", varnum, 1))) into :newvars separated by ' '
    from sashelp.vcolumn
    where libname = upcase("&lib.") and memname=upcase("&dt.") and 
    1 <= varnum <= 2;
quit;

data work._original_table;
    set &lib..&dt.;
    rename &newvars.;
run;

/* select values that are not child of other values (pure parent table) */
proc sql noprint;
    create table _combine1
    as select * from
    _original_table
    where VAR1 not in (select VAR2 from _original_table);
quit;

/* join the pure parent table and its update table to the original table multiple times */
/* move all child and child's child into one line */
%let nonmissing = 1;
%let i = 1;
%do %while(&nonmissing. > 0);
    %let newfile_num = %eval(&i. + 1);
    %let lastcol_num = %eval(&i. + 2);
    proc sql noprint;
        create table _combine&newfile_num.
        as select a.*, b.VAR2 as VAR&lastcol_num.
        from _combine&i. a
        left join
        _original_table b
        on a.VAR&newfile_num. = b.VAR1;
    quit;

    proc sql noprint;
        select count(*) into :nonmissing
        from _combine&newfile_num.(where=(^missing(VAR&lastcol_num.)));
    quit;
    %put &nonmissing.;

    %let i = %eval(&i. + 1);
%end;

/* remove the last empty column */
data &output. (drop = VAR&lastcol_num.); 
    set _combine&newfile_num.;
run;
%mend TransformTable;

%TransformTable(lib=work, dt=original_table, output=Result_for_2ndTrans)
```

But it is still far from good.

First I use a loop instead of recursion, because I do not know how to do recursion in SAS or SQL.

Second, to stop the loop, I need to check the output file every time. It consumes additional resource and not as beautiful as a base case in recursion.

The final output will also contain an extract empty column which requires additional processing at the end of this macro. If you can work on it and come up with a better solution, please let me know.

For the first transformation, so far I have not yet got any idea to approach the problem.

Comment: If your overall goal is to identify connected components, please refer to this other question that I answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342750/sas-grouping-pairs/32412518#32412518

Comment: Based in SO rules please post what you've tried. Additionally, are these rules that your data follows, or should follow but you need to verify in some manner. And last but not least, can you explain how,you last TO dataset aligns with the from dataset. I can't see the link.

Comment: Last table code macro is here https://gist.github.com/statgeek/14e3aa2a9f718f551cd98134e9ceed30

Comment: Hi englealuze.  If you are planning on working with parent/child relationshipts in SAS, then I *strongly* recommend that you adapt one of the below answers to build out a 'nested set' model.  See (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).  This basically flattens the tree so that you can write a simple SQL queries to navigate the parent/child hierarchy.  Anything else will quickly become hard to query/use/maintain... Once it's in a nested set model life is easy!  I work with parent/child relationships frequently in SAS and use this approach all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have very simple solution of this problem, using `hash table` and `hash iterator`.
I hope this generete a correct results. You need to check.

```
proc sort data=original_table;
    by parent child;
run;

data _null_;
    length path $32767 longest 8;

    if _N_ = 1 then do;
        declare hash h();
        h.defineKey('path');
        h.defineData('path','longest');
        h.defineDone();
        call missing(path, longest);

        declare hiter hi('h');
    end;

    set original_table end=last;
    put "PARENT: " parent " CHILD: " child;

    longest = 1;
    path = parent;
    h.ref();
    put "ADD NEW SOURCE: " path=;

    rc = hi.first();
    do while(rc = 0);
        if substr(path, lengthn(path), 1) = parent then do;
            longest = 0;
            h.replace();
            longest = 1;
            path = cats(path, child);
            h.ref();
            put "ADD CHILD: " path=;
        end;
        rc = hi.next();
    end;

    rc = hi.first();
    do while(rc = 0);
        if substr(path, 1, 1) = child then do;
            longest = 0;
            h.replace();
            longest = 1;
            path = cats(parent, path);
            h.ref();
            put "ADD PARENT: " path=;
        end;
        rc = hi.next();
    end;

    if last;
    h.output(dataset: 'result(where=(longest = 1))');
run;

data result;
    set result;
    len = lengthn(path);
run;

proc sort data=result;
    by descending len path;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want do is recursive processing of the dataset. SAS is not really build to do this outside the macro processor. Your will have to use something like `goto` to build a recursive function. The resulting code is quite messy. Hash tables will help to keep track of already used parent/child pairs.

This solution works, but could be further optimized:

```
data transformed_table;
length var1 - var10 $1;

if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash h(dataset:"original_table ");
    declare hiter hi("h");
    h.definekey("parent", "child");
    h.definedone();
    call missing(ref);

end;

set original_table end = eof;

array var [*] var1 - var10;
var1 = parent; ref = 2; 
var[ref] = child;
start:
check = 0;
do i = 1 to (n);
    set original_table (rename=(parent=p1 child=c1) obs=1 ) point=i nobs=n;
    rc = hi.first();
    do while (rc = 0);
        if h.check(key:p1, key:c1) eq 0 and var[ref] = p1 then do;
            ref + 1;
            var[ref] = c1;
            check = 1;
        end;
        rc = hi.next();
        if check = 1 then do;
            h.remove(key:var[ref - 1], key:var[ref]);
            goto start;
        end;
    end;    
end;

keep var1 - var10 ;
if eof then h.output(dataset: 'id');
run;

proc sort data = transformed_table; by var1 var2; run;
proc sort data = id; by parent child; run;
data transformed_table;
    merge transformed_table
          id (in = a rename=(parent=var1 child=var2))
          ;
    by var1 var2;
    if a;

run;
```