# Identify related value pairs in datasets with sas

Tags: join, sas, dataset

I have a dataset with word synonym information (many rows)
Brief example of dataset is shown below.
Information of synonym of each word is presented.

```
Word Synonym
C01  C02
C01  C05 
C02  C02
C02  C05
C03  C04
C05  C06
C11  C12
..   ..
```

From the above dataset, word-synonym relationship can be identified as follows.

C01-C02-C05-C06
C03-C04
C11-C12

After execution of sas codes, I want a dataset of the form shown below.

```
Word Synonym1 Synonym2 Synonym3
C01  C02      C05      C06
C03  C04
C11  C12
```

I tried redundant steps of inner join, but it seemed to be a lot of unnecessary processes.

Comment: Do you have SAS/OR licensed?  It has many procs for finding connected subgraphs from your type of data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAS - grouping pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342750/sas-grouping-pairs)

Answer (score 1):

I hardly can find a good solution in SAS (in other languages this is much easier to solve). The below approach is not good, because it tries to write all group into a single variable which will quickly run out if you have a lot of records. Plus it relies on '#' as a separator. If your words can have this character, you probably would want to change it to something different.

```
data groups;
    set testData nObs=numObs;

    array groups [*] $32767 group1-group100;
    retain groupN 0 group1-group100;

    categorized = 0;

    * Search for the word or synonym in the existing groups;
    if (groupN >= 1) then do;
        do currentGroup = 1 to groupN;
            if (index(groups[currentGroup], "#"||strip(word)||"#") and index(groups[currentGroup], "#"||strip(synonym)||"#") = 0) then do;
                    groups[currentGroup] = strip(groups[currentGroup])||strip(synonym)||"#";
                    categorized = 1;
            end;
            if (index(groups[currentGroup], "#"||strip(word)||"#") = 0 and index(groups[currentGroup], "#"||strip(synonym)||"#")) then do;
                    groups[currentGroup] = strip(groups[currentGroup])||strip(word)||"#";
                    categorized = 1;
            end;
            if (index(groups[currentGroup], "#"||strip(word)||"#") and index(groups[currentGroup], "#"||strip(synonym)||"#")) then do;
                    categorized = 1;
            end;

        end;
    end;

    * If the word and synonym were not found in the existing groups, create a new one;
    if (categorized = 0) then do;
        groups[groupN + 1]  = "#"||strip(word)||"#"||strip(synonym)||"#";
        groupN = groupN + 1;
    end;

    * Split the groups into unique key/value pairs;
    if (_n_ = numObs) then do;
        length key value $200;
        keep key value;
       do currentGroup = 1 to groupN;
            if (not missing(groups[currentGroup])) then do;
                key = scan(groups[currentGroup], 1, '#');
                do j = 2 to countC(groups[currentGroup],'#');
                    value = scan(groups[currentGroup], j, '#');
                    if (not missing(value)) then do;
                        output;
                    end;
                end;
            end;
       end;
    end;
run;

proc sort data = groups;
    by key;
run;

proc transpose data = groups out=result(drop = _:) prefix=synonym;
    by key;
    var value;
run;
```